# Sun GC maxtenuringthreshold

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Have a question about Sun GC. The Sun FAQ (old one for 1.4.2) says that the throughput collector does not use the MaxTenuringThreshold (MTT) parameter. Its used only for CMS.
http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html

> (12) What should I do if my application has mid- or long-lived objects?
>
> - Objects that survive a young generation collection have a copying cost (part of the algorithm for a young generation collection is to copy any objects that survive). Mid- or long-lived objects may be copied multiple times. Use the -XX option MaxTenuringThreshold to determine the copying costs. Use -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0 to move an object that survives a young generation collection immediately to the tenured generation. If that improves the performance of the application, the copying of long-lived objects is significant. **Note that the throughput collector does not use the MaxTenuringThreshold parameter**.

I dont know how to verify this, but if its true, how does the throughput collector determine when to promote the young objects to the tenured generation ? Is it done everytime the young generation fills up (in other words MTT = 0 ? ).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a modern (1.6.0) Sun GC, you can download the source code and work out for yourself *exactly* what is going on.  But of course, the behavior could change with different patch levels.

Here are some more recent documents that refer to the -XXmaxTenuringThreshold option:

- [Java Tuning White Paper](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html) - Sun  (2005)
- ["The most complete list of -XX options for Java 6 JVM"](http://www.md.pp.ru/~eu/jdk6options.html) - Eugene Kuleshov (2006)

and various hints show up in Google searches.  But I cannot find any definitive documentation or a definitive answer to your question on the web.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Unfortunately I am not a developer, so the source code will not really help me much :( I will keep digging and if I find something, will status back.

Answer (score 0):

Checking OpenJDK 1.6 source code for [psScavenge.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/psScavenge.cpp) (= `-XX:+UseParallelGC` = throughput collector) we find

```
if (AlwaysTenure) {
    _tenuring_threshold = 0;
} else if (NeverTenure) {
    _tenuring_threshold = markOopDesc::max_age + 1;
} else {
    // We want to smooth out our startup times for the AdaptiveSizePolicy
    _tenuring_threshold = (UseAdaptiveSizePolicy) ? InitialTenuringThreshold :
                                                MaxTenuringThreshold;
}
```

In this case (OpenJDK 1.6), `MaxTenuringThreshold` is not used *only* when `-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is activated. Then, a [default initial value of 7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp) is used instead.

IMHO, the sentence in bold does mean JDK 1.4.2 will use a default/calculated maximum value to determine when to promote young objects.

If you want to check the values, you can use `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution`

```
 Desired survivor size 48286924 bytes, new threshold 10 (max 10)
 - age   1:   28992024 bytes,   28992024 total
 - age   2:    1366864 bytes,   30358888 total
 - age   3:    1425912 bytes,   31784800 total
```